# Updating a value in an NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to update a specific key in an `NSMutableArray`. The array is called **ListForTable** and I am trying to update the key **statusReport**. There are 4 objects in the array. I am trying to update the first.The following is causing an error:

```
[ListForTable replaceObjectAtIndex:[[ListForTable objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"statusReport"] withObject:@"No edits"];
```

The array is created in the following way:

```
[ListForTable addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: itemName, @"itemName", @"", @"statusReport", nil]];
```

Can anyone explain why?

The error message is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 1087320 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2c57df87 0x39f1ac77 0x2c49b331 0xbe9bb 0x2f9fc86d 0x2f9fc5dd 0x300511f7 0x2fcc5b51 0x2fcdd933 0x2fcdf8cb 0x2fadc615 0xab051 0x2fa2d497 0x2fa2d439 0x2fa1804d 0x2fa2ce69 0x2fa2cb43 0x2fa26451 0x2f9fccc5 0x2fc70513 0x2f9fb707 0x2c544807 0x2c543c1b 0x2c542299 0x2c48fdb1 0x2c48fbc3 0x337c4051 0x2fa5ba31 0x604d5 0x3a4b6aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Explain what the objects in the array are. Why are you trying to replace an item in the array when you say you just want to edit the item stored in the array?

Comment: I just want to replace the what is stored in the key 'statusReport'. I have added a bit more to the question that might help. Could it be a dictionary issue?

Comment: That's good to know it's causing an error.  But, you see, errors usually come with *error messages*, and while you may never read them, they are often useful to the rest of uf.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks - error message included.

Comment: Don't write "long chain polymer" statements.  Do each step as a separate line, assigning to temps in-between.  Then you can debug much easier.  (You're passing a pointer as the index to `replaceObjectAtIndex`, but it expects an integer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error:

```
[ListForTable replaceObjectAtIndex:[[ListForTable objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"statusReport"] withObject:@"No edits"];
```

You are getting your parameters mixed up.

```
[ListForTable replaceObjectAtIndex:...]
```

should be taking an `integer`

But

```
[[ListForTable objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"statusReport"]
```

is probably not an integer.

Rather than replace it, get the pointer to it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *entry = [[ListForTable objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
```

and update it:

```
entry[@"statusReport"] = @"No edits";
```

and then replace:

```
[ListForTable replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[entry copy]];
```

Logic being: you can't modify an NSDictionary (it is *immutable*) so you need a *mutable* copy that you can change. Once you change it, you need to replace it.

the

```
[entry copy]
```

bit makes it an immutable dictionary again.

Truthfully, it doesn't look like you want this array to contain immutable objects anyway, but I hope this explains your issues

Comment: It does - you have solved the problem. Brilliant. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ListForTable replaceObjectAtIndex:
 [[ListForTable objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"statusReport"]
 withObject:@"No edits"];
```

Second line is your "index" but it appears to be an object of some sort.

Trying to parse your intention, I'm thinking maybe you aren't trying to do:

```
ary[0] = "something else";
```

You are trying to modify something in the array?

If so you probably want to do something more like this:

```
MyCoolObject *o = [ListForTable objectAtIndex: 0];
[o setSomethingOrOther: @"No Edits"];
```

However if you were just trying to swap out something in the array.  You need to do something like:

```
[ListForTable replaceObjectAtIndex: 0 withObject: @"whatever!"];
```

Don't call this while iterating over your array.  Also don't name a variable starting with a capital letter.

Comment: I get the replaceObjectAtIndex bit. But when you just want to replace one part of an object based on the key ....

Comment: You need to get a better idea of what your objects are.  Spend some time and read the collections docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html   You may want to structure you data a bit differently to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do:

```
[[ListForTable objectAtIndex: 0] setObject:@"no edits" forKey:@"statusReport"];
```

Comment: Also, davbryn is right ,you have to create your sub dictionary as a mutable dictionary: [ListForTable addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: itemName, @"itemName", @"", @"statusReport", nil]];